# Adding constraints in SDCAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, sdcalertview

I'm using a the pod SDCAlertView, I need to add an imageView + a textField to my content view, however I am having trouble with my constraints, below is my code.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "kalafina")
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
let alert = AlertController(title: "Testing", message: "1234")
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
alert.contentView.addSubview(imageView)


let imageHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
let imageWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
let imageCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alert.contentView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let imageTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alert.contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
let imageBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alert.contentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
alert.view.addConstraint(imageTopConstraint)
alert.view.addConstraint(imageBottomConstraint)
alert.view.addConstraint(imageHeightConstraint)
alert.view.addConstraint(imageWidthConstraint)
alert.view.addConstraint(imageCenterXConstraint)

alert.addAction(AlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Preferred))
alert.addAction(AlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in

    print("Sending")

}))
alert.present()
```

This is my result[image]

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: According to https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView/issues/146, he mentioned that the alert should size accordingly if I add my constraints right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your constraints to `alert.view`, but you should be adding them to `alert.contentView`. If you do that everything works as expected.

Comment: toItem: alert.contentView, pretty sure I added to contentview

Comment: Yeah, but you then call `alert.view.addConstraint()`. This loads the view before it is ready to be loaded. If you change that to `alert.contentView.addConstraint()` it should work fine.